# Find earliest date in r with pmin() in the presence of missing data

Tags: r, date, minimum

I am currently trying to create a new variable to return the earliest date across two variables. I've used the `pmin()` function and have had no problem in the instances where there are dates available across **both** variables. In the instance where there is a missing date on **one variable**, but a date in the other, ideally I would like the code to return the date in the latter variable. Instead, an NA is returned and I haven't figured out how to solve this yet.

My code is as follows:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005),
                 disease_code = c('1', '1' ,'0', '1','0'),
                 Date_of_diagnosis_1 = c(NA,'13/06/1997',NA,'18/02/2005',NA),
                 Date_of_diagnosis_2 = c('12/06/1998',NA,NA,'18/09/2001',NA))

df$Date_of_diagnosis_1 <- as.Date(df$Date_of_diagnosis_1, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df$Date_of_diagnosis_2 <- as.Date(df$Date_of_diagnosis_2, format="%d/%m/%Y")

df <- transform(df, earliest_date = pmin(Date_of_diagnosis_1, 
                 Date_of_diagnosis_2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

UPDATE: na.rm was in the wrong position as highlighted by users Duck and Wimpel. The above code now works as desired.

Comment: your sample data is not correct...

Comment: Currently your dates are strings. What date is `18/20/2005`?

Comment: also.. try: `df <- transform(df, earliest_date = pmin(Date_of_diagnosis_1, 
                                         Date_of_diagnosis_2, na.rm=TRUE) )`.... in your code, the `na.rm = TRUE`  is in the wrong position.

Comment: `pmin()` should work even with `NA`, you have to pass `na.rm=T` inside `pmin()` in `transform()`

Comment: My apologies, this has been updated!

Thank you both for spotting that na.rm=T was in the wrong position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` way of things

```
library( data.table )
#make it a data.table
setDT(df)
#set dates as real date
cols = grep( "^Date", names(df), value = TRUE )
df[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), .SDcols = cols]
#find minumum date in date-columns
df[, earliest_date := do.call( pmin, c( .SD, list( na.rm = TRUE ) ) ), .SDcols = cols ]

#      ID disease_code Date_of_diagnosis_1 Date_of_diagnosis_2 earliest_date
# 1: 1001            1                <NA>          1998-06-12    1998-06-12
# 2: 1002            1          1997-06-13                <NA>    1997-06-13
# 3: 1003            0                <NA>                <NA>          <NA>
# 4: 1004            1                <NA>          2001-09-18    2001-09-18
# 5: 1005            0                <NA>                <NA>          <NA>
```